# How do you set, clear and toggle a single bit in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, numbers, bit-manipulation

How to set, clear, toggle and check a bit in JavaScript?

Comment: @user JavaScript and C/C++ are different languages. Very helpful to have different answers from them both.

Answer (score 272, accepted):

To get a bit mask:

```
var mask = 1 << 5; // gets the 6th bit
```

To test if a bit is set:

```
if ((n & mask) != 0) {
  // bit is set
} else {
  // bit is not set
}
```

To set a bit:

```
n |= mask;
```

To clear a bit:

```
n &= ~mask;
```

To toggle a bit:

```
n ^= mask;
```

Refer to the [Javascript bitwise operators](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators).

Answer (score 37):

I want to add some things (with thanks to @cletus)

```
function bit_test(num, bit){
    return ((num>>bit) % 2 != 0)
}

function bit_set(num, bit){
    return num | 1<<bit;
}

function bit_clear(num, bit){
    return num & ~(1<<bit);
}

function bit_toggle(num, bit){
    return bit_test(num, bit) ? bit_clear(num, bit) : bit_set(num, bit);
}
```

Comment: This is great thanks.  Can you explain why bit_test works?  I understand the right shift to move the interesting bit to the rightmost position, but I get lost trying to understand what the intermediate value is and why its remainder when divided by 2 is nonzero when set.

Comment: After you get the wanted bit to rightmost position, you simply test if the new value is impair (new_value % 2 != 0). An impair number will have bit0 = 1 or else bit0 = 0 (because bit0 weight is 2 to power 0 which is 1)

Comment: I think "impair" should be "odd" (1, 3, 5, 7, ...).

Comment: Yes, I have a french background. I used the french word for "odd" (couldn't edit to correct my comment)

Comment: Do you have similar functions for testing numbers beyond the 32-bit range?

Answer (score 24):

**Get Bit**

```
function getBit(number, bitPosition) {
  return (number & (1 << bitPosition)) === 0 ? 0 : 1;
}
```

**Set Bit**

```
function setBit(number, bitPosition) {
  return number | (1 << bitPosition);
}
```

**Clear Bit**

```
function clearBit(number, bitPosition) {
  const mask = ~(1 << bitPosition);
  return number & mask;
}
```

**Update Bit**

```
function updateBit(number, bitPosition, bitValue) {
  const bitValueNormalized = bitValue ? 1 : 0;
  const clearMask = ~(1 << bitPosition);
  return (number & clearMask) | (bitValueNormalized << bitPosition);
}
```

Examples has been taken from [JavaScript Algorithms and Data Structures](https://github.com/trekhleb/javascript-algorithms) repository.

Answer (score 7):

I built a BitSet class with the help of @cletus information:

```
function BitSet() {
    this.n = 0;
}

BitSet.prototype.set = function(p) {
    this.n |= (1 << p);
}

BitSet.prototype.test = function(p) {
    return (this.n & (1 << p)) !== 0;
}

BitSet.prototype.clear = function(p) {
    this.n &= ~(1 << p);
}

BitSet.prototype.toggle = function(p) {
    this.n ^= (1 << p);
}
```