# Javascript get single bit

Tags: javascript, bit-manipulation

I have an integer and i want to check if a single bit is 0 or 1.

What is the best practise for doing that?

An example of what i'm doing at this moment:

```
const myInt = 8; // Binary in 32 Bit integer = 00000000000000000000000000001000
const myBit = myInt << 28 >>> 31; // 00000000000000000000000000000001

if (myBit === 1) {
    //do something
}
```

But i think that this isn't the best methode for doing this.

Have you any better idea?

**EDIT:**
It is always the same bit i want to check, but the integer is different

Comment: Why don’t you think this is the best way of doing it? How would you imagine a better approach to look like?

Comment: `myInt & 8`?...

Comment: please be more specific about whetrher the bit is still in same position

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1436438/how-do-you-set-clear-and-toggle-a-single-bit-in-javascript

Comment: Maybe this will help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1436448/4673847

Comment: which bit would you like to check?

Answer (score 5):

```
myInt = 8+4; // 1100
n = 3;
(myInt >> n) & 0x1; //  1
n = 2;
(myInt >> n) & 0x1; //  1
n = 1;
(myInt >> n) & 0x1; //  0
n = 0;
(myInt >> n) & 0x1; //  0
```

general solution shifts your number by N bits to right, and applies bitmask, that leaves only last bit, all other are set to 0

Comment: Instead of `0x1` we can use `0b1` as a binary literal

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use the bitwise AND

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators

```
my32Bit = 123414123;
twoBy7 = 128;

//check the 7th bit
if (my32Bit & twoBy7) {
  // should return 1 if the 7thbit is 1
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could take the bit and a [left shift `<<`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators#Left_shift) with [bitwise AND `&`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators#(Bitwise_AND)) operator.

```js
var value = 10,
    bit;
    
for (bit = 0; bit < 4; bit++) {
    console.log(bit, !!(value & (1 << bit)));
}
```