# Draw rectangle for each bit that is 1

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators

I have a canvas with a max number of 16 rectangles drawn to it.

I'm receiving this binary number from a server: `100101101` (or `301` in decimal).

Pretending that I want to associate my rectangles to this binary (one rectangle per bit), I need to hide each rectangle for each bit that is `0` (or draw a rectangle for each bit that is `1`, as you like).

So (if we look at `100101101`) in my canvas I would have the first rectangle drawn, then a space, then two more rectangles, then another space, etc.

I'm scratching my head a lot around this one, as I'm really new to bitwise operation and bitmask. I think that I need to use bitwise operation and bitmask for this, but maybe not...

Here's my base code (with no function to manipulate my bits yet):

```js
    //Referencing canvas
    var canvas = document.getElementById("my-canvas");
  var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");


    //Make Canvas fullscreen and responsive
     function resize() {
   canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
   canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
  }
  window.addEventListener('resize', resize, false); resize();
  
  

  //Default Y pos to center;
  var yPos = canvas.height - 70;
  //Default X position
  var xPos = canvas.width / 2.2;

  var maxRectangles = 16;

 function drawAllRectangles() {

   //Position, size.
   var rectWidth = 70;
   var rectHeigth = 25;
   var dy = rectHeigth + 15;
   ctx.fillStyle = "yellow";

   
   var newPos = yPos;
         var i;
         for (i = 0; i < maxRectangles; i++) {
             ctx.fillRect(xPos,newPos,rectWidth,rectHeigth);
             newPos -= dy;
         }
    }

  drawAllRectangles ();
```

```css
canvas {background-color: #131217}

body { margin: 0; overflow: hidden; }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Draw Rect from bit</title>
    
  </head>


  <body>
  
  <canvas id="my-canvas"></canvas>
  
   </body>


</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use 2 bitwise operator that are "<<" -"LEFT SHIFT", "&"-"AND", you can see explain what you should do it

```
    var binaryVal;
var shiftVal;

var calculatedShiftVal =0;

binaryVal = 4; // 0000 0100
//I will try to explain that shiftVal it is basicall is 1(one) when you use "<<" operator with number that means it shifted from right to left
//Below code what happened after shift operator
shiftVal = 1;//0000 0001
calculatedShiftVal = shiftVal<<0;//0000 0000 0000 0001
console.log(calculatedShiftVal);
calculatedShiftVal = shiftVal<<1;//0000 0000 0000 0010
console.log(calculatedShiftVal);
calculatedShiftVal = shiftVal<<2;//0000 0000 0000 0100
console.log(calculatedShiftVal);
calculatedShiftVal = shiftVal<<3;//0000 0000 0000 1000
console.log(calculatedShiftVal);
calculatedShiftVal = shiftVal<<4;//0000 0000 0001 0000
console.log(calculatedShiftVal);
calculatedShiftVal = shiftVal<<5;//0000 0000 0010 0000
console.log(calculatedShiftVal);
calculatedShiftVal = shiftVal<<6;//0000 0000 0100 0000
console.log(calculatedShiftVal);
calculatedShiftVal = shiftVal<<7;//0000 0000 1000 0000
console.log(calculatedShiftVal);
calculatedShiftVal = shiftVal<<8;//0000 0001 0000 0000
console.log(calculatedShiftVal);
calculatedShiftVal = shiftVal<<9;//0000 0010 0000 0000
console.log(calculatedShiftVal);
calculatedShiftVal = shiftVal<<10;//0000 0100 0000 0000
console.log(calculatedShiftVal);
calculatedShiftVal = shiftVal<<11;//0000 1000 0000 0000
console.log(calculatedShiftVal);
calculatedShiftVal = shiftVal<<12;//0001 0000 0000 0000
console.log(calculatedShiftVal);
calculatedShiftVal = shiftVal<<13;//0010 0000 0000 0000
console.log(calculatedShiftVal);
calculatedShiftVal = shiftVal<<14;//0100 0000 0000 0000
console.log(calculatedShiftVal);
calculatedShiftVal = shiftVal<<15;//1000 0000 0000 0000
console.log(calculatedShiftVal);

//Then we use "&" "AND" operator with shiftVal and your number from server it is basically if your number and shiftVal gives to us "0" then you wont be draw your rectangle if it is grater than 0 then you can draw rectangle
//for example you want to check 4th rectangle value and your number is 17
//0000 0000 0001 0000  --> shiftVal<<4
//0000 0000 0001 0001  --> represent 17
//0000 0000 0001 0000  -->represent after &
var yourVal = 17;
console.log((shiftVal<<4)&yourVal); // result is 16 then you can draw it
//other example you want to check 3th rectangle value and your number is 17
//0000 0000 0000 1000  --> shiftVal<<3
//0000 0000 0001 0001  --> represent 17
//0000 0000 0000 0000  -->represent after & everthing is 0 now and your value is 0
console.log((shiftVal<<3)&yourVal); // result is 0 then you shouldn't draw it
```

Enjoy

Comment: Perhaps a for loop would help?

Comment: Yes he should use loop I just give clue to him how to access value as binary

Comment: Thanks @FerhatBAŞ ! Really clear explanation, I'll start from there !

Comment: Alright, it was pretty simple to do actually! I did a Fiddle as an example: https://jsfiddle.net/simon_duchaine/Lx5r2027/.

Answer (score 0):

As Ferhat BAS pointed out, use the `&` bitwise AND operator, and the `<<` left shift operator.

> Bitwise AND - Returns a one in each bit position for which the corresponding bits of both operands are ones.
>
> Left shift - Shifts a in binary representation b (< 32) bits to the left, shifting in zeroes from the right.

[Here's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1436448/3783155) a very good answer on how to manipulate bits of a number using bitwise operators.

Now, you need a condition to test in the for loop in `drawAllRectangles`, or else all rectangles will be drawn "unconditionally". You could use this:

`if (mask & 1) ...`

```
function drawAllRectangles(data) {

        //Position, size.
        var rectWidth = 70;
        var rectHeigth = 25;
        var dy = rectHeigth + 15;
        ctx.fillStyle = "yellow";


        var newPos = yPos;
        var i;
        for (i = 0; i < maxRectangles; i++) {
            var mask = 1 << i;
            // if mask & 1 == 1, then the if statement evaluates to true, as 1 is "truthy" in javascript
            if (mask & 1) ctx.fillRect(xPos,newPos,rectWidth,rectHeigth);
        }
}
```