# Is there any way to get Bit level info from Bytes using Buffer javascript package?

Tags: javascript, react-native, bluetooth-lowenergy, buffer

```
const session = {"data": [0, 91, 56, 110, 221, 112, 0, 0, 4, 1, 0, 0, 60, 2, 34, 255, 255, 255, 167, 237], "type": "Buffer"}

const buffer = new Buffer(session)
const buffer1 = buffer.subarray(14, 15)
console.log("buffer1",buffer1) //output : 34
```

I want to get bit level data as image shows.

Here are details of bit level data
[image]

Comment: Does this help you? https://stackoverflow.com/a/1436448/7473793

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you have the octet of interest then you can do bitwise operations on it to get the bits of interest. This can be simplified by having a small function.

For example:

```js
var Buffer = require('buffer/').Buffer;
const session = {"data": [0, 91, 56, 110, 221, 112, 0, 0, 4, 1, 0, 0, 60, 2, 34, 255, 255, 255, 167, 237], "type": "Buffer"};
const buffer = new Buffer(session);
const data = buffer.readUInt16LE(13);
console.log("Data", data);

function bits(value, bitsStart, bitsWidth){
  return (value >>> bitsStart) & ( Math.pow(2, bitsWidth) - 1);
}

console.log('Binary value:', (data).toString(2).padStart(16, '0'))
console.log('Session type:', bits(data, 0x00, 0x04))
console.log('Aborted:', bits(data, 0x04, 0x01))
console.log('Goal Complete:', bits(data, 0x05, 0x01))
console.log('Goal Extended:', bits(data, 0x06, 0x01))
console.log('Auto Letdown:', bits(data, 0x07, 0x01))
console.log('Leak Detected:', bits(data, 0x08, 0x01))
```

Giving the output:

```
Data 8706
Binary value: 0010001000000010
Session type: 2
Aborted: 0
Goal Complete: 0
Goal Extended: 0
Auto Letdown: 0
Leak Detected: 0
```

Comment: Hi @ukBaz, Thanks for response and it is working fine. Could you please elaborate how I can get 8 & 9th position data. i.e. data=[2, 34].

Comment: Updated to include extracting the data from the buffer. It wasn't clear from your original question that you were trying to extract a Uint16.

Comment: hi, can I ask you quesiton. Does this method ***readUInt16LE(13)*** mean convert the byte from index 13 to int16?

Comment: The parameter denotes the number of bytes to be skipped before starting to read from buffer. int16 reads two byes